# DevExpress WinForms Skins - now showing

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, skins

I have 2 desktop apps:

1. .NET 4.8.0 Framework app, DevExpress 22.2
2. .NET 8 Core app DevExpress 23.1.7
   Both are WinForms-base. in #1 the "Dark Side" skin shows for entire app, but in #2 it does not.
   Unfortunately, my subscription is expired and DevExpress is not answering my questions.
   Here is my code in .NET Core app (#2) in Program.cs Main():

   ```
            SkinManager.EnableFormSkins();
            SkinManager.EnableMdiFormSkins();
            BonusProvidersRegistrator.Register(); // used in .NET 8
            //DevExpress.UserSkins.BonusSkins.Register(); // used  in >NET 4.8.0

            UserLookAndFeel ulaf = UserLookAndFeel.Default;
            ulaf.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = false;
            UserLookAndFeel.Default.SetSkinStyle("Dark Side");

            var services = new ServiceCollection();

            ConfigureServices(services);

            // Build ServiceProvider
            ServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            Application.Run(ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MainForm>());
   ```

I also tried without this line but it does not make a difference:

```
UserLookAndFeel.Default.SkinName = "Dark Side";
```

Any ideas? Is it a bug in DevExpress 23.1.7 or compatibility issue in 23.1.7?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your project file and add:

```
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Win.BonusSkins" Version="23.1.7" />
```

Then add to your main window in MainForm_Load:

```
WindowsFormsSettings.DefaultLookAndFeel.SetSkinStyle(skinStyle: DevExpress.LookAndFeel.SkinStyle.DarkSide);
```